# Post request not working in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am beginner for Ionic application development and i am trying to post data to server using below code but my code does not hit server url and i am getting failure response please help me what should for complete my requirement

### home.ts:

```
doLogin() {

    //Headers parameters
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    //Parameters
    let postParams = {
      empId: 'em2',
      password: 'password123',
      deviceId: '957334kjhsd'
    }

    this.http
        .post('http://2c631a4d.ngrok.io/employeeLogin', postParams, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              alert("success")
            },
            err => {
              alert("failure")
            }
        );
  }
```

Comment: did you try to console log the error object?

Comment: its not hitting my server url,I am not getting any requsts at server side

Comment: Have you tried hitting the same url and params through Postman plugin ?

Comment: its working fine i postman

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Because the above code seems totally fine

Comment: response with status :0 for URL in ionic 3

Comment: i am getting above exception

Comment: I am running my code in web browser is this problem?

Comment: Sorry can you '@Ivaro18' me on next comment? I didn't receive a notification of your comment :) Does it say something about `CORS` or `Cross Origin...`? Because then you should configure your Server sided code to send Allow-Cross-Origin headers on every response (including `OPTIONS` request method)

Comment: so server side what should we do?

Answer (score 0):

You cant post to server-side due to cross-domain issue, you must allow same origin request in your server, allow localhost request in your server. 
If you are using asp.net server, add some line of code in your webconfig and your router class.

Ionic http post is a few buggy. You must pass your data as querystring like this:

```
Let params = "id="+MyId"+"&title="+MyTitle;
this.http.post(url, params, options) .map(res => res.json())
```